# How to consistently skip (or not skip) x axis labels in R base graphics

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I want to create a figure where for various reasons I need to specify the axis labels myself. But when I specify my labels (some have one digit, some two digits) R suppresses every other two-digit label because it decides there isn't enough room to show them all, but it leaves all of the one-digit labels, leaving the axis looking lopsided.

Is there a way to suppress labels consistently across the whole axis, based on whether any of them need to be skipped? Note: I have a lot of plots with varying scales, so I was looking for something I could use for all of them - I don't want to render all the labels for every plot, or to skip every other label in every plot. Suppressing labels will be desirable for some plots and not for others. I just want to skip every other label consistently, if that's what R chooses to do for the particular plot.

(Here is an example [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm9n7.png) of what I mean. What I want is for the "6%" label to also be suppressed in the x axis.)
Example code:

```
library(labeling)

df <- data.frame("estimate" = c(9.81, 14.29, 12.94), 
             "lower" = c(4.54, 6.25, 5.12), 
             "upper" = c(12.85, 20.12, 15.84))
ticks <- extended(min(df$lower), max(df$upper), m = 5, only.loose = TRUE, 
              Q=c(2, 5, 10))

png("examplePlot.png", width = 1200, height = 900, pointsize = 10, res = 300)
bars <- barplot(df$estimate, horiz = TRUE, col = "white", border = NA, 
            xlim = c(min(ticks), max(ticks)), xaxt = "n", main = "Example")
arrows(df$lower, bars, df$upper, bars, code = 3, angle = 90, length = 0.03)
points(df$estimate, bars, pch = 20)

tickLabels <- paste(ticks, "%", sep = "")
axis(1, at=ticks, labels = tickLabels, cex.axis=1)  
axis(2, at = bars, labels = c("c", "b", "a"), lwd = 0, las = 2)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the size of the plot, so you'll have to plot each label separately:

```
axis(1, lwd.ticks = 1, labels = FALSE, at = ticks) # plot line and ticks
i <- seq(1,length(ticks),2) # which labels to plot
for(ii in i)
  axis(1, at = ticks[ii], labels = tickLabels[ii], cex.axis = 1, lwd = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want to _always_ skip every other label on every plot though - what I was hoping for is to consistently skip or not skip, based on whether _any_ labels need to be skipped for that plot. (For example, I have some plots that already have 5 well-spaced labels anyway, so if I skip every other one I'd end up with labels only at e.g. 10%, 50%, and 90%). I've edited the question accordingly.